# URL syntax for connecting with server from the client side

Tags: java, h2

I went around the Internet for this question and I just can't figure it out.

I am developing a Java Application on Netbeans and I'm connecting to the H2 Database Engine through Netbeans IDE. I am not interested in using the console.

The code to connect to H2 is as follows (from the client side):

```
Connection connt = null;
String url = "jdbc:h2:tcp://" + SERVER_IP + ":" + SERVER_PORT + "//C:/Databases/businessApp;";
connt = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", "");
```

When the code reaches the `.getConnection()` method, it stays there and does nothing.
I am almost sure that there is something wrong with the URL syntax.

`SERVER_IP` and `SERVER_PORT` are defined earlier and are not null.

Comment: Remove semi colon(;) from url after **businessApp**.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Any other ideas? 
If I use the following code it works as when I use it I start the server and act as the client as well: String url = "jdbc:h2:\\Databases\\businessApp"; But I want it to connect from other computers as well

Comment: Did you start the H2 Server?

Comment: Yes, I did start the H2 server!
I checked it by entering the ip:port on a browser and, hence, verifying the connection.

Comment: The code to start the server is as follows:
import org.h2.tools.Server;

public class startWebServer {

    Server server;

    public void webServer(){

        try {

            server = Server.createWebServer(
                new String[] { "-trace" }).start();

            System.out.println(server.getStatus());
        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error with Server: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        startWebServer webServ = new startWebServer();
        webServ.webServer();
    }
}

Comment: I have changed the "Server.createWebServer" to "Server.createTcpServer" and now it works but on my computer only. If I try to connect from another computer, it does not work. I have also changed the SERVER_IP and SERVER_PORT to localhost as per the H2 documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: This is an update: I have found something called h2.bindAddress. I have set the address to my localhost. Will this work for remote access and NOT for local access? For local access, it works even without binding the address. I'm really struggling with this one and I need help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the culpript is your final connection string which looks like

```
"jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.1.154:8080//C:/Databases/businessApp"
```

and h2 apparently doesn't recognize UNC paths.

The above under GNU/Linux instead would work because of the different convention used for paths:

```
"jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.1.154:8080/home/user/Databases/businessApp"
```

The solution I found is to add a slash after the port number, your string would thus become:

```
"jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.1.154:8080/C:/Databases/businessApp"
```

this works both in Linux and Windows

Answer (score 0):

I think semi colon(;) after "businessApp" is the culprit. Try after removing it.

Comment: If I use the following code it works as when I use it I start the server and act as the client as well:
String url = "jdbc:h2:\\Databases\\businessApp";
But I want it to work from other computers as well.